# Warning Messages when downloading packages from Github - untar2

Tags: r, github, warnings, tar

Whenever I download a package from github and a few other packages, I get this warning message:

```
Warning messages:
1: In untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir) :
  skipping pax global extended headers
2: In untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir) :
  skipping pax global extended headers
```

Is there a way to fix this?

This is an example package:

```
devtools::install_github('daroczig/fbRads')

Downloading GitHub repo daroczig/fbRads@master
 √  checking for file 

'C:\Users\nknauer\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpWW5UJm\remotes11f43012405a\daroczig- 
   fbRads-2c08d3e/DESCRIPTION' ...
-  preparing 'fbRads': (459ms)
√  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... 
-  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
-  checking for empty or unneeded directories
-  building 'fbRads_3.0.0.tar.gz'

* installing *source* package 'fbRads' ...
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
  converting help for package 'fbRads'
    finding HTML links ... done
    fbRads                                  html  
    fb_api_most_recent_version              html  
    fb_api_version                          html  
    fb_insights                             html  
    fbad_add_audience                       html  
    fbad_assign_users_to_account            html  
    fbad_check_curl_params                  html  
    fbad_check_fbacc                        html  
    fbad_create_account                     html  
    fbad_create_ad                          html  
    fbad_create_adset                       html  
    fbad_create_audience                    html  
    fbad_create_campaign                    html  
    fbad_create_creative                    html  
    fbad_create_image                       html  
    fbad_create_lookalike_audience          html  
    fbad_delete_audience                    html  
    fbad_get_adaccount_details              html  
    fbad_get_adaccounts                     html  
    fbad_get_client_ad_accounts             html  
    fbad_get_client_pages                   html  
    fbad_get_my_ad_accounts                 html  
    fbad_get_owned_ad_accounts              html  
    fbad_get_owned_pages                    html  
    fbad_get_pixels                         html  
    fbad_get_search                         html  
    fbad_init                               html  
    fbad_insights_get_async_results         html  
    fbad_list_ad                            html  
    fbad_list_adset                         html  
    fbad_list_audience                      html  
    fbad_list_campaign                      html  
    fbad_preview_ad                         html  
    fbad_reachestimate                      html  
    fbad_read_ad                            html  
    fbad_read_adset                         html  
    fbad_read_audience                      html  
    fbad_read_campaign                      html  
    fbad_read_creative                      html  
    fbad_remove_audience                    html  
    fbad_request                            html  
    fbad_request_next_page                  html  
    fbad_share_audience                     html  
    fbad_update_ad                          html  
    fbad_update_adset                       html  
    fbad_update_campaign                    html  
    fromJSONish                             html  
    is.FB_Ad_Account                        html  
    print.FB_Ad_Account                     html  
    this_function_name                      html  
    url_parse                               html  
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
*** arch - i386
*** arch - x64
* DONE (fbRads)
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning messages:
1: In untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir) :
  skipping pax global extended headers
2: In untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir) :
  skipping pax global extended headers
```

Comment: I'm not sure we need to "fix" this - this is a warning, not an error. Maybe the extended headers are just not present.

Since you chose one of @daroczig's, maybe he can tell.